# Recorrer Array de fechas y separar secuencias consecutivas en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo una array multidimensional de fechas y valores en PHP, el cual necesito separarlo en otro array por rangos consecutivos. Es decir que en el ejemplo debajo, hay dos valores con fechas y necesito separarlo en bloques de fecha consecutivas y su respectivo valor.

```
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-01',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-02',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-03',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-04',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-06',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        5 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-08',
          'Valor' => 10,
        ),
        6 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-01',
          'Valor' => 20,
        ),
        7 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-02',
          'Valor' => 20,
        ),
        8 => 
        array (
          'Fecha' => '2021-10-03',
          'Valor' => 20,
        ),
      )
```

El resultado esperado debería ser otro array multidimensional como el que se muestra debajo.  Separando las fechas en bloques de inicio fin y valor.

```
array (
    array (
      'FechaInicio' => '2021-10-01',
      'FechaFin' => '2021-10-04',
      'Valor' => 10,
    ),
    array (
      'FechaInicio' => '2021-10-06',
      'FechaFin' => '2021-10-06',
      'Valor' => 10,
    ),
    array (
      'FechaInicio' => '2021-10-08',
      'FechaFin' => '2021-10-08',
      'Valor' => 10,
    ),
    array (
      'FechaInicio' => '2021-10-01',
      'FechaFin' => '2021-10-03',
      'Valor' => 20,
    )
)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Cuál es el criterio para decidir `FechaInicio` y `FechaFin`?

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder. El criterio de inicio y fin es cuando las fechas correlativas dejan de serlo. Por ejemplo en el primer array falta la fecha 2021-10-05. Entonces el inicio es la primer fecha y el fin es el 2021-10-04. Espero haber sido claro. Gracias

Comment: Pero ¿qué pasa con los índices 6,7 y 8? que tienen las mismas fechas que 0,1 y 2.

Comment: La clave valor de esos índices son distints. Unos son valor 10 y otros valor 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de resolver esto sería usando un [iterador](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.iterator.php), el cual te permitirá con mayor facilidad guardar una referencia del elemento previo y del que le sigue, para poder hacer las comparaciones.

Aquí un código funcional, asumimos que tu array inicial se llama `$origin`  (cámbialo por su nombre real).

He comentado lo que se ha ido haciendo, para que puedas entenderlo:

```
$obj = new ArrayObject( $origin );
$it = $obj->getIterator();
$i=0;
while( $it->valid() )
{
    #Referencia al elemento actual
    $current=$it->current();
    #Avanzamos el iterador
    $it->next();
    #Referencia al siguiente elemento
    $next=$it->current();
    
    #Si $outPut[$i] no existe lo creamos 
    if(empty($outPut[$i])) {
        #Asignamos FechaInicio
        $outPut[$i]['FechaInicio']=$current['Fecha'];
    }

    #Creamos dos objetos DateTime para ver la diferencia en días        
    $currentDate=new DateTime($current['Fecha']);    
    $nextDate=new DateTime($next['Fecha']);
    #Creamos un intervalo entre las dos fechas
    $interval = $currentDate->diff($nextDate);
    #Verificamos si el intervalo es de más de un día
    if($interval->days > 1) {
        #Asignamos FechaFin y Valor y cambiamos de índice
        $outPut[$i]['FechaFin']=$current['Fecha'];
        $outPut[$i]['Valor']=$current['Valor'];  
        $i++;       
    }   
}
var_dump($outPut);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["FechaInicio"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-01"
    ["FechaFin"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-04"
    ["Valor"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["FechaInicio"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-06"
    ["FechaFin"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-06"
    ["Valor"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["FechaInicio"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-08"
    ["FechaFin"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-08"
    ["Valor"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["FechaInicio"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-01"
    ["FechaFin"]=>
    string(10) "2021-10-03"
    ["Valor"]=>
    int(20)
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a probarlo.